# Matlab: adjacency matrix from patch object

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, adjacency-matrix

I have a Matlab `patch` object, in which the `Faces` property is a list of vertex index triplets, so each row represents one triangular face. For example:

```
   293    13     1
   433    13   293
   293   294   433
   434   433   294
```

In this case, the first row defines a face stretched between the vertices 1,13 and 293. My actual matrix has about 200,000 vertices and 400,000 faces.

I'd like to form a vertex adjacency matrix, e.g. a sparse binary square matrix `A` s.t. `A(i,j)` is `true` iff vertices `i`,`j` have a shared face.

Is there any efficient way to do it in matlab? A simple `for` loop searching for the occurrence of one face in each iteration is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be used for arbitrary dimensional simplicial data:

```
halfedges = nchoosek(1:size(Faces,2), 2);
edges = [halfedges; fliplr(halfedges)];
A = logical(sparse(Faces(:,edges(:,1)), Faces(:,edges(:,2)), 1));
```

If memory overhead is more of a concern to you than speed, you could loop over the edges:

```
nv = max(Faces(:)); % Get the maximum vertex id.

halfedges = nchoosek(1:size(Faces,2), 2);
edges = [halfedges; fliplr(halfedges)];
A = sparse(nv,nv);
for i = 1:size(edges,1)
    A = A | logical(sparse(Faces(:,edges(i,1)), Faces(:,edges(i,2)), 1, nv, nv));
end
```

An alternative could be to build a `triangulation` object and then use the built-in [`isConnected`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.isconnected.html) function.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `sparse` constructor, let `nv` be the number of vertices you have, then

```
A = sparse( Faces(:,1), Faces(:,2), 1, nv, nv ) + ...
    sparse( Faces(:,2), Faces(:,3), 1, nv, nv ) + ...
    sparse( Faces(:,3), Faces(:,1), 1, nv, nv );
A = spfun( @(x) 1, A + A.' ); %// make it symmetric
```

Comment: Is that `spfun` really faster than `A = (A+A.')>0;`?

Comment: @LuisMendo I did not test it, but I suspect it is. `spfun` only works on the non-zero elements while `(A+A.')>0` actually evaluates *all* entries of the `nv`-by-`nv` matrix.